# How to E2E test on Electron desktop app with Playwright

Tags: electron, e2e-testing, playwright, playwright-test

I try to write E2E test with playwright but something is wrong.

When I was initialize the test, test passed but actually, block did not go inside the bracket.
It also passes the test when I enter the wrong selector.

*The code is below:*

```
import { _electron as electron } from 'playwright';
import { test, expect, ElectronApplication, Page, BrowserContext, Locator } from '@playwright/test';

test.describe('Add Connection', async() => {
let electronApp: ElectronApplication;
let firstWindow: Page;
let context: BrowserContext;

    test.beforeAll(async() => {
        electronApp = await electron.launch({ args: ['.']} );
    
        const appPath = await electronApp.evaluate(async({ app }) => {
            return app.getAppPath();
        });
        console.log(appPath);
    });
    
    test('Try Connection', () => {
        electronApp.on('window', async(page) => {
    
            await page.getByTestId('settings').click({delay: 1000});
            await page.getByTestId('connection').click({delay: 1000});   
    
        });
        
    });
    
    test.afterAll(async() => {
        await electronApp.close();
    });

});
```

I haven't seen enough documentation about E2E testing on Electron. How can we write a test where we can go to different pages by clicking on the buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. The inside of 'Try Connection' test doesn't work because electronApp.on() is a callback function.
To write ElectronJS & Playwright test I choose these steps:

I got a Page object (firstWindow) after that I clicked on the buttons and went to the place I wanted to test.

The final code:

```
import { _electron as electron } from 'playwright';
import { test, expect, ElectronApplication, Page } from '@playwright/test';

test.describe('Add Connection', async() => {
    let electronApp: ElectronApplication;
    let firstWindow: Page;

    test.beforeAll(async() => {
        electronApp = await electron.launch({ args: ['.']} );
        firstWindow = await electronApp.firstWindow();
    });

    test('Try Connection', async() => {
        await firstWindow.title();
        await firstWindow.click('xpath=//*[@id="sidemenu-container"]/a[3]', {delay: 1500});
        await firstWindow.click('xpath=//*[@id="***"]/app-settings/div/div[1]/button[1]', {delay: 1500});
        await firstWindow.click('xpath=//*[@id="***"]', {delay: 1500});
        await firstWindow.getByPlaceholder('***').fill('emir connection');
        await firstWindow.locator('#***').selectOption({label: '***'});
        await firstWindow.click('xpath=//*[@id="***"]', {delay: 2000});
        // for the wait, (fake click)
        await firstWindow.click('xpath=//*[@id="***"]', {delay: 7000});
    });

    test.afterAll(async() => {
        await electronApp.close();
    });

});
```